# open the browser using phantomjs selenium webdriver in C #

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

am using selenium Webdriver in C # along with phantomjs driver , it would be possible at the end of my code I open the browser on the screen where you were ?

Comment: No, you can't do that, because PhantomJS is fully headless. There is no head, but you can take screenshots at various points.

Comment: ok , Thanks For Help Artjom B.